# If the column name of primary ,auto increment field is not id , can $this->db->insert_id() function be used

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-insert-id

I am new to Codeigniter..

So this is my table:

request_id | login_name  | login_password | reg_date  | status

Can I use `$this->db->insert_id()` to get last inserted id  if the primary auto increment column name is `request_id` instead of `id`?

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Why you don't try by using it yourself ?  Have a go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) in MySQLi does not care about the *column name*, just that the column is AUTO_INCREMENT. It returns;

> The value of the AUTO_INCREMENT field that was updated by the previous query. Returns zero if there was no previous query on the connection or if the query did not update an AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use.

`$this->db->insert_id()` gives you id of last inserted record, so no need to change the method name.

refer [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/63052/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes using $this->db->insert_id() you can get the id of last inserted record in table.
Like this :

```
     <?php    
    class InsertRecord extends CI_Model {
    var $tablename = "test_table";
    var $primaryID = "request_id";

        function insertRecord(){
             $insertArr['login_name'] = $_POST['login_name'];
             $insertArr['login_password'] = $_POST['login_password'];
             $insertArr['reg_date'] = $_POST['reg_date'];       
             $insertArr['status'] = $_POST['status'];
             if ($this->db->insert($this->tablename, $insertArr)) {
                $lastInsertedID = $this->db->insert_id();
             }
        }
     }
    ?>
```

In $lastInsertedID variable you will get id of last inserted record.

Hope this will help you... :)